# How to remove the comma in title bibmacro for ieee style in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, ieee-style

I have been doing a long google search to a pretty simple question. In my thesis, I am using `biblatex` with bibtex as a backend and the ieee bibstyle and have loaded the `ngerman` language in `babel`. When I print the bibliography, the first thing that is printed is the author followed by the title which is set in quotation marks. However, at the end of the title within the quotation marks it includes a comma (see below).

[image]

All I want is to remove this comma. I found some solutions with bst files, however, `biblatex` does not use bst files (anymore?). Could you please give me some advice what to do?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Added MWE example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
    @incollection{Bauernhansl.2016,
    author = {Bauernhansl, Thomas},
    title = {Die Vierte Industrielle Revolution -- Der Weg in ein wertschaffendes Produktionsparadigma},
    pages = {1--31},
    bookpagination = {page},
    publisher = {{Springer Berlin Heidelberg}},
    isbn = {978-3-662-53253-9},
    series = {VDI Springer Reference},
    editor = {Vogel-Heuser, Birgit and Bauernhansl, Thomas and ten Hompel, Michael},
    booktitle = {Handbuch Industrie 4.0 Bd.4},
    year = {2016},
    abstract = {},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-662-53254-6_1},
    location = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
    booksubtitle = {Allgemeine Grundlagen},
    edition = {2nd ed.},
    file = {Bauernhansl 2016 - Die Vierte Industrielle Revolution:C\:\\Users\\Tolga\\Documents\\Citavi 6\\Dissertation\\Citavi Attachments\\Bauernhansl 2016 - Die Vierte Industrielle Revolution.pdf:pdf}
   }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=ieee,
    natbib=true]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space}
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
    {\newunit\usebibmacro{title}}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{}\usebibmacro{title}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}
    {}
    {}

\begin{document}

\cites{Bauernhansl.2016}
\printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Add the following to your preamble

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}
{\newunit\usebibmacro{title}}
{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{}\usebibmacro{title}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}
{}
{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
{\usebibmacro{title}}
{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{}\usebibmacro{title}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}
{}
{}
```

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2021new,
    title={A new method to fit logistic functions with wind turbines power curves using manufacturer datasheets},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, {Al-Motasem} Ihssan and Alzaareer, Khaled and Harasis, Salman and {Al-Odat}, Zeyad and Obeidat, Mohammad and Mansour, Ayman and Wu, Di and Salem, Qusay},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={15},
    number={16},
    year={2021},
    month={12},
    doi={https://doi.org/10.1049/rpg2.12309}
}
@incollection{Bauernhansl.2016,
    author = {Bauernhansl, Thomas},
    title = {Die Vierte Industrielle Revolution -- Der Weg in ein wertschaffendes Produktionsparadigma},
    pages = {1--31},
    bookpagination = {page},
    publisher = {{Springer Berlin Heidelberg}},
    isbn = {978-3-662-53253-9},
    series = {VDI Springer Reference},
    editor = {Vogel-Heuser, Birgit and Bauernhansl, Thomas and ten Hompel, Michael},
    booktitle = {Handbuch Industrie 4.0 Bd.4},
    year = {2016},
    abstract = {},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-662-53254-6_1},
    location = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
    booksubtitle = {Allgemeine Grundlagen},
    edition = {2},
    file = {Bauernhansl 2016 - Die Vierte Industrielle Revolution:C\:\\Users\\Tolga\\Documents\\Citavi 6\\Dissertation\\Citavi Attachments\\Bauernhansl 2016 - Die Vierte Industrielle Revolution.pdf:pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=numeric-comp,
bibstyle=ieee,
natbib=true]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}
{\newunit\usebibmacro{title}}
{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{}\usebibmacro{title}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}
{}
{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
{\usebibmacro{title}}
{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{}\usebibmacro{title}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}
{}
{}


\begin{document}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]
    
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

To add space after quotation marks, renew `\intitlepunct` as follows

```
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addbthinspace}
```

You may also try to replace `\addbthinspace` with `\addspace` and see which choice fits you best

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help for my code. I added a minimum working example in the question.

Comment: Thank you. The updated version works now. I could have guessed to change it to incollection. There is one last thing though. The comma after the author seems to disappear to but I wanted to keep that. Could you also explain how it works so I can adjust it myself?

Comment: @Toggo. I edited the answer

Comment: Perfect! This is what I wanted. Could you maybe also show me how to add a space after the second quotation mark?

Comment: Could you help me with the missing space and also explain how your solution works?

Comment: @Toggo, I edited my answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for incollection but how can I add a comma after the quotation mark for articles?